# How to get content from specific tags when using file_get_contents

Tags: php, tags, text-files, file-get-contents

For example i have one .txt file, called cache.txt. It contains some information, and i need to get content from `<span class="date">**THESE**</span>` tags. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Use a [DOM parser](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+dom+parser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

**Example:**

cache.txt

```
<span class="abc">Lorem Ipsum</span>
<span class="date">THESE</span>
<span class="def">Dolor sit amet</span>
```

file.php

```
<?php    
include 'simple_html_dom.php';    
$html = file_get_html('cache.txt');    
echo $html->find('span[class=date]',0);  //Output: THESE
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Check this out it will bring the result**
//cache.txt
<span class="date">**THESE**</span>

//index.php
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('cache.txt');
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$data = $xml->xpath('/span');
echo $data[0][0];
?>
```